# How to fix the position of a widget in floatlayout - kivy

Tags: kivy, position

I have a big issue related to pos_hint and positioning of widgets in floatlayout kivy. So now basically  I have two MDTextField Which has y_scroll set to True. so that their size will increase over each wrap. so the widgets are placed one over another such that input_field_1 is first followed by input_field_2. These widgets are ofcourse placed in FlaotLayout and this FlaotLayout is in a ScrollView..Whenever the height of the textfield increases it would also result in increase in the height of floatlayout.. So my problem is if u would write for example 20 lines in first field such that it's height increases by 20 times than at that point it will overlap the second widget..And their will be no sign of that widget .
How can I avoid such accidents and any help is appreciated .

My code is as follows :

```
str = '''

ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x : False
    FloatLayout:
        height : input_field_1.height + input_field_2.height + 100
        size_hint : None,None
        
        MDTextField:
            id : input_field_1
            mode : 'rectangle'
            size_hint : None,None
            pos_hint : {'x' : 0.1,'top': 0.8}
            y_scroll : True
            multiline : True
        MDTextField:
            id : input_field_2
            mode : 'rectangle'
            size_hint : None,None
            pos_hint : {'x' : 0.1,'top': 0.5}
            y_scroll : True
            multiline : True

'''
class My_4app(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(str)
My_4app().run()
```

And if you think if their is any better widget for the purpose please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I think a `BoxLayout` would do what you want. Try replacing:

```
FloatLayout:
    height : input_field_1.height + input_field_2.height + 100
    size_hint : None,None
```

with:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: self.minimum_height
```